# Issue: reloading current page on a browser trigger an API request to backend

Tags: reactjs, semantics

I need help. I've been searching online, tried different things, but no luck.

I have a react + semantics UI app, that runs on separate docker containers (1 for frontend on port 3000, 1 for fastapi/nginx backend on port 80 & 443).

My react Router setup works fine when I use, http://localhost:3000, which correctly routes it to  http://localhost:3000/login for the login form. Typing in http://localhost:3000/login on the browser URL works as well. Reloading the page (ctr+R in Windows or command+r in Mac) would work fine, no issue. I see in the browser's Developer tool's debugger, that no request was actually sent to the backend, with a page reload.

But issue is with https.  When I type https://localhost on the browser url, it correctly routes it to https://localhost/login, which will pop-up a login form like with the http.  However, when I reload the page or when I type in https://localhost/login directly on the url and enter, I got the "Method Not Allowed" error instead of the login form.  In the Web developer tool's debugger, I got a http response back with an error code of 405,
"Method Not Allowed", a GET method being used with the request.  So, it looks like an API request was sent to the backend, which responds back with a 405 error since I have a POST /login endpoint, not GET /login endpoint.

Why is that, and how I can fix this?  Can I prevent the browser from sending the API request to the backend with a GET, with a page refresh or when I use https://localhost/login?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try and access your backend directly using https?

Comment: @DanielDuong, I am not totally understanding your question.  When I use postman and send a POST with https://localhost/login to the backend, it works fine, getting back a 200 response.  On the browser, when I use https://localhost/login and enter, I got the "Method Not Allowed" error.  When I use https://localhost/, the page is correctly routed to https://localhost/login, which pops up a login form.  But when I enter, or reload the page, the form is gone and I got that error message.

Comment: Also, the login form asks user to enter username/pwd.  Once the form is submitted, I will call an POST api request to the backend.   That works fine and my frontend sends back  a 200 response.  It's just that, when I reload the page, while I am on https://localhost/login, or when I use https://localhost/login and enter, I got the error message and there is an GET api request to the backend.

Comment: Can you post some part of your code here? It's important to see what is going on.

Comment: @Pitter, sorry I can't post, since it has quite a number of files.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, both backend and frontend contain a route called `/login` in the same port?

Doesn't that complicate things? In that case, changing either route to something like `_login` solves the issue right?

My understanding is that visiting `/` does a browser based javascript redirection to `/login` which renders the react component. But directly visiting `/login` (or refreshing) hits the backend server.

Comment: @Rahul.A.Krishna The way I understood it is that the frontend runs on port 3000 with a get login route, whereas the backend runs on port 80 & 443 with a post route.

80 is the default web port. So if you have not changed anything the request without a specified port should go by default to port 80 and therefore to the backend which would explain the issue. So how did you route the default request to localhost without a port from port 80 to 3000? That's where the issue probably is.

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Dustin for your feedbacks.  I still can't figure out how to fix it.  But I decided to remove the https out of our local development, to make things easier.  So, I just use `http://localhost/login` going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but just in case anyone comes across this.

I was trying to figure out exactly the same issue today with a React app giving a 405 when navigating to /login, and I (finally...) found that I had an API route called /login in my proxy set up as well as a /login route set up for my react app. Same for /logout.

I changed my React app to use something different (/sitelogin and /sitelogout in my case) and hey presto, it started working as expected.

I guess the proxy URL was overriding the React routing (I'm new to React) so that /login was being used to try and make a regular HTTP request.